# I can't scope anything onto my angular dialog(reviewForm) from the DialogController?

Tags: angularjs, forms, mongodb, dialog, angular-material

Below I have a button that is attached to each venue list item. So each list item has its own button. Also, each list item is a object. So when I click one of buttons I need to somehow grab the ID from that specific list item and be able to use it in my dialogcontroller.

```
<div class="results">
<div class="searchbox col-md-6 form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search venues" class="form-control" ng-model="filterTerm">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="well" ng-repeat="venues in venues | filter: filterTerm">
            <h3>{{venues.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{venues.info}}</p>
                <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAdvanced($event, venues)" flex-sm="100" flex-md="100" flex-gt-md="auto">Add a Review</md-button>

            <button>See Reviews</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My get call to my JSON file. Also, This is my ng-click function that is using mdDialog (which opens a popup window with a reviewForm.html as its content.

```
    $http.get('/getMarkers').success(function(response) {
$scope.venues = response;
console.log($scope.venues);

});

$scope.showAdvanced = function(ev, venues){
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController(ev,venues),
        templateUrl: 'views/reviewForm.html',
        parent:angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose:true
    })
};
```

This is my DialogController which is handling the content(reviewForm.html) that is being rendered in my mdDialog window.

```
function DialogController($scope, venues, $mdDialog) {

console.log(venues);
$scope.rate = 0;
$scope.max = 5;


$scope.hoveringStaff = function (value) {
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
    console.log($scope.overStar);
};

}
```

This is the html that is going into the dialog

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Review Form">
{{something}}
<md-toolbar>
    {{venues}}
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
        <h2>Review Form</h2>
        <span flex></span>
    </div>
</md-toolbar>
<md-dialog-content>
    {{$scope.something}}
        <label>{{something}}Show Attended:  </label><input type="text" ng-model="show"><br/>
        <label>Date:  </label><input type="date" ng-model="date"><br/>
        <label>Staff Friendliest:  </label><uib-rating ng-model="rate" max="max"  on-hover="hoveringStaff(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="['one','two','three']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating><br/>
        <label>Sound Quality: </label><input type="text" ng-model="sound"><br/>
        <label>Favorite Drink/Cocktail:  </label><input type="text" ng-model="drink"><br/>
        <label>Nearby Bar/Food Recommendations: </label><input type="text" ng-model="nearby"><br/>
        <label>Comments: </label><input type="text" ng-model="comments"><br/>
        <label>Venue Rating: </label><br/>
        <md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="sendReview()">Primary</md-button>
</md-dialog-content>
```

I need the ID because I am going to posting a form to the database and need to add the form content to the selected list item. Sorry if this is confusing, let me know if you have any questions. Thanks!

Comment: with "grab ID" do you mean "index" ?

Comment: if the id is in the object just pass the venues from the ng-click and then you'll have the object, if you want the $index then just pass it in the ng-click but if you want the html attribute id I guess you can just get it with angular.element ... first two would be preferable I guesss

Comment: I mean the venue.id so when I submit the form in my dialog, I'm able to see what list item i'm referencing. Will the list index work the same way?

Comment: if you want to pass the venues.id which is an attribute in the Object then just do ng-click="showAdvanced($event, venue)", then in your controller att that parameter to the function and pass it to the model

Comment: So what I tried was.. ng-click="showAdvanced($event, venues) then  $scope.showAdvanced = function (ev, venues) then function Dialog Controller($scope, venues, $mdDialog). I got a injector error tho

Comment: Now, I get undefined in the dialogcontroller when I try to console.log venues

Comment: Ok I got it to work. Thanks jony

Comment: Ok so now I can't scope anything on my dialog window (reviewForm.html) after the fix..

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to use `locals` or `resolve` to pass objects to the new controllers, because of angular's dependency injection, passing objects to the controller will not work (i.e MyController($scope, a, b)).

ex:

```
$mdDialog.show({
   locals: {
      venue: venue
   }
});
```

or with resolve

```
$mdDialog.show({
   resolve: {
      venue: function(){return venue;}
   }
});
```

Another issue which I think is a typo, is in the `ng-repeat` directive `venues in venues` which should be `venue in venues`.

Reference the view values to `venue` object(i.e venue.drink, venue.date, ...ect) instead of `$scope`, will make it easier to pass it back to the parent controller.

```js
function MainCtrl($http, $scope, $mdDialog) {
  /*
  $http.get('/getMarkers').success(function(response) {
    $scope.venues = response;
    console.log($scope.venues);
  });
 */

  $scope.venues = [{
    name: 'Venue #1',
    info: 'Info',
    date: new Date(),
    drink: 'A drink'
  }];

  $scope.showAdvanced = function(ev, venue) {
    $mdDialog.show({
      controller: 'DialogController',
      template: '<md-dialog aria-label="Review Form">\
{{venue.name}}\
<md-toolbar>\
{{venue}}\
<div class="md-toolbar-tools">\
    <h2>Review Form</h2>\
    <span flex></span>\
</div>\
</md-toolbar>\
<md-dialog-content>\
{{venue.name}}\
<label>{{venue.name}}Show Attended:  </label><input type="text" ng-model="venue.show"><br/>\
<label>Date:  </label><input type="date" ng-model="venue.date"><br/>\
<label>Staff Friendliest:  </label><uib-rating ng-model="venue.rate" max="max"  on-hover="hoveringStaff(value)" on-leave="overStar = null" titles="[\'one\',\'two\',\'three\']" aria-labelledby="default-rating"></uib-rating><br/>\
<label>Sound Quality: </label><input type="text" ng-model="venue.sound"><br/>\
<label>Favorite Drink/Cocktail:  </label><input type="text" ng-model="venue.drink"><br/>\
<label>Nearby Bar/Food Recommendations: </label><input type="text" ng-model="venue.nearby"><br/>\
<label>Comments: </label><input type="text" ng-model="venue.comments"><br/>\
<label>Venue Rating: </label><br/>\
<md-button class="md-raised md-primary" ng-click="sendReview()">Primary</md-button>\
</md-dialog-content>',
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      targetEvent: ev,
      clickOutsideToClose: true,
      locals: {
       venue: venue
      }
    })
  };
}



function DialogController($scope, venue, $mdDialog) {
 $scope.venue = venue;
  console.log(venue);
  $scope.rate = 0;
  $scope.max = 5;


  $scope.hoveringStaff = function(value) {
    $scope.overStar = value;
    $scope.percent = 100 * (value / $scope.max);
    console.log($scope.overStar);
  };

}
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial'])
.controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl)
.controller('DialogController', DialogController);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/0.11.0/angular-material.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.6/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div class="results">
<div class="searchbox col-md-6 form-group">
    <input type="text" placeholder="search venues" class="form-control" ng-model="filterTerm">
    <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li class="well" ng-repeat="venue in venues | filter: filterTerm">
            <h3>{{venue.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{venue.info}}</p>
                <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="showAdvanced($event, venue)" flex-sm="100" flex-md="100" flex-gt-md="auto">Add a Review</md-button>

            <button>See Reviews</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
    </body>
</html>
```